# sequence 3 images right after another to display on a image view

Tags: swift, loops, selector, func

My swift code below in the func below displays 2 images in a image view fan. My code below right now successfully does that but it can only display 2 images. I want to display a, b, cd, for a second each then repeat in a endless cycle.

```
let image1 = UIImage(named: "a.png")
let image2 = UIImage(named: "b.png")
let image3 = UIImage(named: "cd.png")
  var fan = UIImageView()




@objc func alterImage() {
    fan.image = fan.image == image2 ? image1 : image2
    perform(#selector(alterImage), with: self, afterDelay: 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
@objc func alterImage() {
    fan.image = fan.image == image1 ? image2 : fan.image == image2 ? image3 : image1
    perform(#selector(alterImage), with: self, afterDelay: 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview) has a property called [`animationImages`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621068-animationimages) exactly por this purpose, one to control its duration [`animationduration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621058-animationduration), and one called [`animationRepeatCount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621070-animationrepeatcount) to control its repetition. You just need to set it to zero for an endless cycle. Once you have setup those properties you just need to call `UIImageView`'s method [`startAnimating()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621061-startanimating)

---

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image1 = UIImage(named: "a")!
        let image2 = UIImage(named: "b")!
        let image3 = UIImage(named: "c")!
        imageView.animationImages = [image1, image2, image3]
        imageView.animationDuration = 1
        imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0
        imageView.startAnimating()
    }
}
```